# Connecting to ec2 server issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm connecting to a ec2 using Remote Desktop Connection with the Admins Login and Password but after connecting to the server I see the Windows's User Login Page asking for the password a second time, so I'm needing to type the password twice. It wasnt like this before, when connecting to the server the user would already be logged in, this started after a windows update in my machine. How can I connect with the user already logged like before?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and it looks like it's related to recent patches.

https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/03/23/microsoft_rdp_patch_credential_security_support_provider_protocol/

Suggested fixes are to patch clients and servers, and possibly re-enter your saved RDP password on the client.

Comment: I deleted the credentials then saved them again with the same password as before and it worked.