# Server asks for login on every connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When I remote desktop to a server, it shows the list of users and I have to enter the password to login.

It's never done this before. Why now?

Comment: I also had this problem - answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361233/52768

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the stored credentials and then re-added and saved them.